# Copying from iframe block

Tags: javascript, jquery, clickjacking

I have a clickjacking vulnerable endpoint `https://www.example.com/myaccount`.
At this endpoint there is a block which display the user's API key , which have both public and private keys.

I was able to load the respective endpoint in iframe when the user is logged in.

I did the iframe using the below code

```html
<div qjid="quickjack" style="overflow: hidden; width: 775px; height: 227px; position: relative;" id="cksl6">

<iframe name="cksl7" src="https://vulnerableendpoint.example.com/my-account" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -267px; top: -1377px; position: absolute; width: 2880px; height: 1642px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

The above code successfully loaded the respective vulnerable endpoint

Requirement

I need to create an overlay with junk content and when the junk content is copied , the API keys which is under the overlay should be copied.

> One thing to notice , the private key is hidden , it needs to be shown in plaint text by clicking the `Show` button similar to show password

How can I achieve it using javascript ?

Comment: If iframe origin is different than parent page origin you can't access inside it to prevent what you are trying to do

Comment: you are saying that even if i was able to load this in an iframe , i wont be able to access inside it ?

Comment: Correct, if origins are different browsers prevent script access to the frame window due to such abuse over the years

Comment: What if there is no origin validation ? Is it possible ? if yes can you share the code for it , this will be a good finding in my report

Comment: What do you mean by no origin validation? If they are same origin it's not hard to research how to access the DOM inside the iframe

Comment: The origin header value which indicates where a fetch originates from.

Comment: Same origin means same domain, subdomain, port and protocol. If any of those differ between the two urls (page and frame) then browser blocks it from script access